Sharing String Catalog translations across Swift Packages
I am working with two Swift packages and using string catalogs .xcstrings to manage localizations.
Each package has its own specific localization keys, but I also need to reuse some common keys, such as ok_button_title.
Problem
I want to avoid duplicating identical translation entries in each package. Ideally, I would like to have a single source of truth for these shared translations.
I attempted the following code to reference a translation key from the main app’s bundle:
String(
  localized: "ok_button_title",
  table: "Localizable",
  bundle: .main,
  comment: "Ok button title"
)

This retrieves the translations from the main bundle, but it doesn’t automatically create the keys in the string catalog for the Swift package.
Question
Is it possible to reuse translations from the main bundle directly in Swift packages?
Alternatively, is there a way to automatically generate keys in the string catalog for Swift packages? Or is this behavior expected and not a bug?

To manage localizations in a Swift Package using string catalogs .xcstrings, you need to ensure the following:

Bundle Configuration: Use the .module bundle for your Swift Package. This ensures the package-specific translations are loaded correctly.
Swift Tools Version: Your Package.swift file must specify // swift-tools-version: 6.0 or later to support String(localized:table:bundle:comment) strings within a package. Otherwise, use NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:module:comment:)

Steps:
Here’s how you can set up a reusable string catalog for a Swift Package:

Create a .xcstrings file with your desired table name (e.g., Shared.xcstrings).
Add your translations to a swift file in your package.
Build your project to see the translations appearing in the .xcstrings file.

Implementation Example:
Define a localization enum for cleaner and easier retrieval of localized strings:
enum L10n {

  static let okButtonTitle = String(
    localized: "ok_button_title",
    table: "Shared", // Matches the name of your .xcstrings file.
    bundle: .module, // Uses the Swift Package's module bundle.
    comment: "Ok button title"
  )
}

Usage:
To retrieve the localized value in your app:
import YourTranslationsPackageName

let buttonTitle = L10n.okButtonTitle


Well, that is a solution indeed! Thanks!
However I would like to be able to use the bundle parameter as intended - is that possible?

If your translations are located inside the Swift Package, the bundle parameter must be set to .module for proper resolution. As you requested to make it work within a Swift Package, bundle: .module is the only viable answer.
If your translations are implemented in the .xcodeproj of your app (main target), you can use the bundle: .main. In fact, when working within the main app target, you can omit the bundle parameter entirely and simply use String(localized:table:) for convenience.

As it was stated in the initial question - I want to use the main bundle. However the problem here is that new keys don't appear in the string catalog after syncing translations. Is it a bug or a feature?

Using the .main bundle accesses the app’s translations, but keys from a Swift Package’s .xcstrings won’t sync with the app. This is not a bug, it’s by design. String catalogs in Swift Packages are scoped to their module, requiring .module for access. If you want shared translations, centralize them in the app’s .xcodeproj or create a shared package for common keys. .module is the only valid bundle for package-local translations.
